# Почему не работает слайдер?

Tags: html

Я понимаю, что какие-то проблемы с подключением, а именно с порядком. Но никак не могу поставить, чтобы работало все нормально.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<script src="./js/bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://static.codepen.io/assets/editor/live/css_reload-5619dc0905a68b2e6298901de54f73cefe4e079f65a75406858d92924b4938bf.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn-vk.com/js/vk.js?v=2"></script>
```

вот такие подключения внизу. а это код для слайдера:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    // Optional parameters
    effect: 'cube',
    loop: true,
    cubeEffect: {
      shadow: true,
      slideShadows: true,
      shadowOffset: 1,
      shadowScale: 0.8,
    },
    grabCursor: true,
  })
});
```

Comment: Откуда нам знать, если вы код самого слайдера не показали и вообще [mcve] отсутствует

Comment: @andreymal в консоли выдает еще "Ошибка при парсинге значения «cursor». Потерянное объявление."

Comment: Показанный вами код слайдера замечательно работает и никаких ошибок не выдаёт: https://jsfiddle.net/71zbr9dj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Браузеры читают код как люди текст, с лева на право, с верху в низ. Для работы Swiper нужен Jquery а поскольку Swiper в html стоит выше чем Jquery то при инициализации слайдера он не смог найти функции и методы jquery.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/bundle.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://static.codepen.io/assets/editor/live/css_reload-5619dc0905a68b2e6298901de54f73cefe4e079f65a75406858d92924b4938bf.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn-vk.com/js/vk.js?v=2"></script>
```

Всё заработает.

А вы точно подключили swiper css?

Answer (score 1):

Если свайпер работает на jquery, то jquery нужно поднять. Ну а вообще круто было бы полностью ошибку почитать.

Comment: в том то и дело, что консоль чистая. ни одной ошибки

Answer (score 1):

С начала квери потом слайдер потом все остальное